# Wildfly 10 not detecting environmental variable when run as a service in ubuntu

Tags: environment-variables, wildfly8

I have an environmental variable say `APP_PROPERTIES` pointing to `/etc/wildfly/app.properties`. When I run wildfly from console using `standalone.sh` it is taking the properties from the environmental variable, but when I run wildfly as a service, it is not loading the file. The log is as follows:

```
20:36:17,567 WARN  [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Could not load properties from URL [file:]:  (No such file or directory)
```

How to make wildfly load the file from env. I tried setting it in `/etc/default/wildfly` but it is not working.
I am running Wildfly 10 under Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You need to add the variable in `/etc/default/wildfly` and modify the service startup script `/etc/init.d/wildfly`. You need to simply export the declared variable.

Comment: How did you modify the service startup script?